# Trying to make a tornado from text in Photoshop CS6

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text, text-wrap

I am trying to create a tornado/hurricane 3d effect on some text on Photoshop CS6, my knowledge is very limited and I searched a lot before I post a question here but I couldn't find any related material. I tried the transformations of skew, distort, warp but nothing that I tried could give the result I wanted. I am also posting two shapes that I have seen and want to reproduce but instead of lines to have some text curling around:

[image]

[image]

Thank you in advance for your time on this,

Alexios

Comment: You just want to know how to draw a tornado?

Comment: I want to know if there is a tool (Like skew etc)  inside the photoshop that can use to modify a sequence of words to make them in a shape of tornado. Not sure how this works so excuse me if It is a basic question.

Comment: Oh okay, because the sample pictures you provided don't look anything like what you're asking.

Comment: Check type an a path. It will be a mess. I bet there must be a solid stripe where the text seems to be written on and the spaces are adjusted just at the points where thin sides of the characters should be towards the watcher. The solid stripe under the text will provide the continuity.

Comment: It's a job for Illustrator. Extrude the tornado shape, map the words to it. I'll show you when I get home.

Comment: Thank you for the replies, everyone. @webster this will be great if you have a link or a video that shows something similar from the internet as I didn't find something (at least for Photoshop). Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make a word tornado use Illustrator's Effect>3D>Revolve to make a tornado shape and wrap text around it.

Make half of a tornado shape. I drew a rectangle then used the pen tool, clicked the lower point on edge of rectangle, then clicked the upper left corner and dragged right holding Shift until it looked like this.

[image]

I selected the line and and the rectangle and used Pathfinder>Divide, ungrouped and deleted the other piece of the rectangle.

I selected the half tornado and opened Effect>3D>Revolve. I bent the tornado back to make it look higher than the viewer. I slanted it and applied some perspective until I liked it.

[image]
[image]

Say okay to the tornado dialogue for now.

To wrap the text on: you must apply the text as a symbol, this requires that you  prepare and style your text beforehand. Get your text styled how you want and sized for the tornado. Drag it onto the symbols panel and choose export type: graphic.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Now to return to your tornado's 3D window select it, open the Appearances panel and double click the Revolve appearance. Select Map Art and in the following window choose your new text symbol and which side of the tornado you want to put it on.

[image]
[image]

Drag and position the text with preview selected. Slant and scale the text to get good results. Select Invisible Geometry if you want the tornado base to disappear leaving only the text.

[image]

For your other example I made a very crude demonstration but the same approach will work, make the shape with the 3D revolve tool, it can be a cylinder, sphere or hourglass, any wheel shape. Make a custom symbol and wrap it around using the same 3D>Revolve window.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Amazing help!I will try the following  days to see the final result. Thank you on this!!